# Using printf to print a COLORREF type variable

Tags: c, windows, printf

I need to print a variable which is a COLORREF.

Comment: Missing `windows` (or...?) tag? `COLORREF` is not part of C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to break it up into the individual RGB components:

```
printf("R: %i, G: %i, B: %i", GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));
```

this would give you something like:

R: 255, G: 150, B: 75

Answer (score 3):

A [`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just an integer containing an RGB value. You can print a hex representation this way:

```
printf("%06X", color);
```

Note that the order of values is `bbggrr`, so it will look different from the usual `rrggbb` format.